# How to compress images on SERVER

Tags: image, compression

I have a website which is also a social media networking website where user can upload profile, cover & article picture.
 So currently there are around 25000+ Images available many of them are even 2 MB- 10 MB large, so i want to compress them all at once.
 Is that possible if yes then please specify how i can do that, because currently i'm using huge band-witch and also site is pretty slow.
 Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways..But did you tried anything from your side, show it.

Comment: Not yet, I think we can use G-Zip compression with APACHE server, but anything else which can help me..

Comment: Can we see any code...?

Comment: Codes are simple, like with PHP adding pics vis edit profile pae and adding article images via submit_article page, we use codes to store images in specific dir and then echo out whenever someone open profile or post, I used .htaccess to apply some G-Zip compression codes.

Comment: Are they JPEG or PNG or GIF? Are all 25,000 in one single directory? What OS is your server running?

Comment: Do the images all have the same pixel dimensions, or is it part of the problem that some are 4000x3000pixels and some are 256x200pixels?

Comment: Hey MARK yaa all images are PNG, JPEG & GIF format, all are in 3 directories..

Comment: Yaa..some have more pixels and some have less pixels, i want to compress them and store all 3 type of images in three dir in different pixels, sizes..